# firebase nodeJs received email parshing issue

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, mailgun

I am using mailgun received email callback for firebase nodeJs cloud functions but I am not getting form-data request in request variable in nodejs (firebase functions). below is code and response:

Code :

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require("./service-account.json");
var apn = require('apn');
var firebase = require("firebase");

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();

app.use(cors({origin: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})); // for parsing
app.use(multer);

exports.receivedEmail = functions.https.onRequest((app, response) = > {

console.log("app res : " + app.body);

response.status(200).json({
    "msg": "success",
    "error": false
});

});
```

Result :

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recipient"

monica@sandbox51a77de723e741c3b046c60910ee1e48.mailgun.org

--362eb63be3174fc4a7299a0f269f5038

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sender"

chandler@sandbox51a77de723e741c3b046c60910ee1e48.mailgun.org

--362eb63be3174fc4a7299a0f269f5038

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

Re: Sample POST request

--362eb63be3174fc4a7299a0f269f5038

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="from"

I need app.body.subject , app.body.text , app.body.to etc.